# Data fill in specific pattern

Tags: excel, sorting, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to fill data in MS Excel. I am given following pattern:

```
1 2
1 
1 
2 5 
2 5
2 
3 
3 6
3  
4 
4 
5 4
```

And I want my output in following format:

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
2 5 
2 5
2 5
3 6
3 6
3 6
4 
4 
5 4
```

I tried using `if(b2,b2,c1)` in column 3. but that doesn't solve the problem for `a=3 and a=4`.

Any idea how to do this in Excel?

Comment: why `2 2` after `2 5` ?

Comment: Sorry that was a error. I'll fix that.

Comment: have you tried it in VBA ?

Comment: No, i don't know what that is.

Comment: You may visit this ... http://excelvbatutor.com/vba_tutorial.html

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have 2 blanks (next to 4,4 in the second column) shouldn't that be 6,6....

Comment: No, that is correct, few `a` are blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sorting thus:

[image: SO18568673 example]

(the effect of which in this case is merely to move `6` up once cell) and a blank row above:

```
=IF(AND(A2<>A1,B2=""),"",IF(B2<>"",B2,C1))
```

In C2 and copied down should get the result you ask for from the data sample provided.

Comment: Thank you for replying, your solution took care of the blank entries, i.e. `a=4`. But can't manage for `a=3`.